# Encoding not producing expected result

Tags: python, python-3.x, encode

I am currently sending this command `'\x8A\x01\x01\x11\x9b'` through socket.
As there are several commands that I use, I decided to save them in different variables but each made an encode of the variable, the result is different from performing the operation `b'\x8A\x01\x01\x11\x9b'`.

The result of performing `str.encode('\x8A\x01\x01\x11\x9b')` gives me `'\xc2\x8A\x01\x01\x11\xc2\x9b'`.

```py
import socket 
import sys  
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  
server_address = ('ip', port)  
sock.connect(server_address) 
sock.sendall(b'\x8A\x01\x01\x11\x9b') # response true  
instructions = '\x8A\x01\x01\x11\x9b' 
sock.sendall(str.encode(instructions)) # response False
```

Comment: Can you show the code you use to send the command through the socket and where you save the commands in variables?

Comment: What do you mean by "save them in different variables"? `cmd = b'\x8A\x01\x01\x11\x9b'` looks right. Not sure how encodings are envolved. A code sample focusing on the bit that's a problem (you may not need the socket code) will help.

Comment: `import socket
import sys

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server_address = ('ip', port)

sock.connect(server_address)

sock.sendall(b'\x8A\x01\x01\x11\x9b') # response true

instructions = '\x8A\x01\x01\x11\x9b'
sock.sendall(str.encode(instructions)) # response False
`

Comment: David, for future reference, don't paste code relevant to the question in comments, it's much harder to read. Edit your original post and put the code there wrapped in code tags (use 3 backticks on each side)

Comment: What result do you **want** encoding them to produce? The default encoding that `str.encode()` uses is `"utf-8"`.

Comment: The `8A` and `9B` characters in `instructions` are being encoded as UTF-8, taking two bytes each - thus destroying their binary value.  Encoding is something that you do with *text*, for binary data you should be using bytestrings exclusively.